# Entity Framework Foreign Key Select

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a model

**Retailer** which has the fields

ID

Name

and another

**Store**

StoreName

RetailerID

In SQL to get the name of the retailer rather than just the ID when selecting all stores I can use a join.

How do I go about this in EF??

```
using (var context = new DBContext())
{    
//Get all stores with the name of the retailer
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access the related Retailer object on the Store object itself, for example:

```
using(var context = new DBContext())
{
    var myStore = context.Stores.First(s => s.StoreName == "my store");
    string retailerName = myStore.Retailer.Name;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case sorry? The store class only has a field called RetailerID not retailer so how do you choose store.Retailer?
Also what if you wanted to select all stores and retailer names in one statement like you can in SQL? Thanks

Comment: In your table, yes, Store has only RetailerID. In EF, if Store and Retailer are linked through a FK, then you will have access to the Retailer as above on the Store.

I know you want to select all, the above is to illustrate how to access Retailer, from that, should be easy to figure out for all stores. You can basically define your own StoreModel class with RetailerName in it, and fill it with Store entity data, and fill its StoreModel.RetailerName from Store.Retailer.Name for example.